# How can I create a frictionless rigid body?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I remove the friction from a rigidbody? I want it to lose no speed over time. I have set the Drag property to 0. However, the model just slows down and eventually stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign [a physics material](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-PhysicMaterial.html) to your object. In this material, set the friction to 0, and the bounciness to some high value. The documentation seems to suggest setting it to 1, but play with it to get the desired effect.